# Can I treat a vertex group like a separate object?

Tags: rigging, cloth-simulation, vertex-groups

I want to know if there is a way to do this, or a work around. I want to apply cloth simulation to specific groups of vertices and its difficult to do that without having to separate the mesh.

Comment: Pinning the not simulated vertices?

Comment: Can you explain your case a little more?